# jQuery token input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I allow users to select input from a jQuery input while they can still type in their input that does not match the suggestion from jquery token input? Like when you add tags for questions here.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a autocomplete widget? which shows the matching options below. Then check this Jquery UI [site](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)